# GCM push notification not working in Android App

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Push notification not working in my app.

When I send push notification it show message as below:

```
GCM HTTP status: 200
GCM response body: {"multicast_id":5052582973644051315,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

My menifest code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.scryp">

    <permission
        android:name="com.scryp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.skryp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".activities.SkrypApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.PushNotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.scryp.activities" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.SignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.CouponActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_coupon"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.CouponDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.DownloadCouponActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.scryp.activities.TutorialActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB4rU0s2yS-3RGu5GQOb_L_JG6_H5toy60" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Change com.example.gcm to com.scryp:

Comment: I changed it but still showing same issue. GCM HTTP status: 200
GCM response body: {"multicast_id":6884053400481394097,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

Comment: Check your api key

Comment: My API Key is correct. I downloaded a GCM Demo app and it is receiving GCM with same API Key but my app not receiving.. there is some issue with my settings, I think.

Comment: Could you please check my menifest where I made mistake please.

Comment: I downloaded a demo app from here: http://download2003.mediafire.com/yd6b4epzdz9g/l62aw7vqbb7e3a4/GcmDemo.zip and this app receiving message with same API Key. But my app not receiving.

Comment: I think you can setup gcm follow this article: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

Comment: attending on package name

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.scryp.activities" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: remove .activities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110062/discussion-between-shivam-s-kara-and-hoang-v-nam).